# What is the interface between a floor and a wall called: a corner, too?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request

> [corner](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/corner_1?q=corner): a part of something where two or more sides, lines or edges
>   join the four corners of a square
>
> I hit my knee on the corner of the table.
>
> Write your address in the top right-hand corner of the letter.
>
> the left/right corner
>
> the north-west/north-east/south-east/south-west corner
>
> A smile lifted the corner of his mouth.
>
> in the corner of something a speck of dirt in the corner of her eye
>
> He scored with a shot into the bottom corner of the goal.
>
> She tucked the ball into the corner of the net.

[image]

A corner is often the interface between 2 adjacent walls. What is the interface between a floor and a wall as shown in the picture called: a corner, too?

**Note**: If I translated literally from Vietnamese (my mother tongue) to English, it would be "**wall-foot**".

Comment: It could still be *corner*. A ***square*** (2 dimensions) has 4 sides, but a ***cube*** (3 dimensions) has 6 sides. If I were to rotate a cube, would some of its corners disappear while others appeared?

Comment: In a basement, that's called a cove joint. If the room in question is **not** part of a basement, then it's a wall-floor joint or a floor-wall joint.  (People who build houses may have a more specialized term.) However, in most cases, most people would just call it "where the wall and floor meet," "where the floor meets the wall," or "where the wall meets the floor." A wooden board or something similar running along the bottom of the wall adjacent to the floor is called a baseboard (or mopboard, skirting board, skirting, etc.), but that's clearly not what you're asking about.

Comment: However, even though I see no difference between a square and a cube in terms of terminology, I don't think you're using the word *corner* correctly even when it comes to a square. And what you're pointing to in the diagram as a corner is not what would normally be thought of as a corner. (Regardless of wall meeting wall or wall meeting floor.) In that picture, it's only the intersection of **3** lines (wall, wall, and floor, or wall, wall, and ceiling) that would be a corner.

Comment: It is not an interface at all. It's where the walls joins the floor.

Comment: What do you call it Vietnamese?  What does a bilingual dictionary offer as a translation?  Are you looking for a technical architectural term, or the phrase that you might use casually?  Can you give an example sentence showing how you want to use this word or phrase?

Comment: @JamesK, If I translated literally from Vietnamese to English, it would be " wall-foot"

Comment: @JasonBassford Actually, I'm not sure that's correct. Admittedly, if you _stand in the corner_ you are standing on the floor, but a _corner cupboard_ fits into the angle between two walls, whether it stands on the floor or hangs.